# Content restrict - depend on Domain Name

Tags: conditional-statements

Two domain name join to one web site .
Eg , Domain A and B link with Web site C.

At contact.php page , 
When user view with domain A, 
I want to hide some content in contact.html.
Eg, images, word etc...

But with Domain B , he can see all the contact.php page .

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7GYVc/)

this demo will log current domain name of site in console

```
var current_domain = document.location.hostname;
console.log(current_domain);
if (current_domain == "example.com") {
    //code for hiding stuff goes here
} else if (current_domain == "example21.com") {
    //code for that page here
}
```